# Performance issue - PL/SQL fetch cursor to table of records with bulk collect

Tags: sql, oracle, performance, plsql, sql-tuning

I want to process a large amount of records and I am using bulk collect instruction to fetch the data into a table of records. However, I am sure there is a more adequate way to achieve what I am looking for. Here is the code:

```
  FUNCTION GET_STORE_ITEMS(I_store           IN   STORE.STORE%TYPE,
                           I_item_status     IN   WIN_STORE.STATUS%TYPE,
                           ----------- output ------------
                           O_item_data       OUT  NB_TAB_ITEM_DETAIL,
                           ----------- error -------------
                           O_error_message   OUT  VARCHAR2)
  RETURN BOOLEAN IS
    -- ----------------------------------
    --            VARIABLES            --
    -- ----------------------------------
    L_program         VARCHAR2(100)     := 'NB_ITEM_INFO_SQL.GET_ITEM_DETAIL';
    L_error_message   VARCHAR2(500)     := '';
    --
    -- ----------------------------------
    --            CURSORS              --
    -- ----------------------------------
     -- 003 begin
  CURSOR C_get_info IS
   -- #004 - begin
     SELECT NB_REC_ITEM_DETAIL(sku, desc_up, system_ind, status, division, div_name, group_no, group_name,
                               dept, dept_name, class, class_name, subclass, sub_name, nb_var_weight,
                              (SELECT upc as primary_ean
                                 FROM upc_ean u
                                WHERE u.sku = tab.sku
                                  AND u.primary_upc_ind = 'Y'
                                  AND rownum = 1),
                              CAST( multiset(SELECT u.upc
                                               FROM upc_ean u
                                              WHERE u.sku = tab.sku
                                                AND u.primary_upc_ind <> 'Y')
                                    AS NB_TAB_ITEM_EAN )
                               )
      FROM (SELECT info.sku,
                   info.desc_up,
                   info.nb_var_weight,
                   info.system_ind,
                   info.status,
                   div.division,
                   div.div_name,
                   c.group_no,
                   b.group_name,
                   info.dept,
                   c.dept_name,
                   info.class,
                   a.class_name,
                   info.subclass,
                   e.sub_name
            FROM (SELECT w.store,
                         w.sku,
                         nvl(wa.nb_var_weight, 'N') nb_var_weight,
                         w.status,
                         ts.desc_up,
                         ts.system_ind,
                         ts.dept,
                         ts.class,
                         ts.subclass
                    FROM win_store w,
                         win_attributes wa,
                         desc_look ts,
                         deps d
                   WHERE w.sku  = wa.sku
                     AND w.store = I_store
                     AND wa.sku = ts.sku
                  --   AND (w.status = I_item_status OR I_item_status IS NULL)
                     AND d.dept = ts.dept
                 UNION ALL
                  SELECT st.store,
                         st.sku,
                         'N' nb_var_weight,
                         st.status,
                         ts.desc_up,
                         ts.system_ind,
                         ts.dept,
                         ts.class,
                         ts.subclass
                    FROM rag_skus_st st,
                         desc_look ts,
                         deps d
                   WHERE st.store = I_store
                     AND ts.sku = st.sku
                 --    AND (st.status = I_item_status OR I_item_status IS NULL)
                     AND d.dept = ts.dept
                 UNION ALL
                  SELECT ps.store,
                         ps.pack_no,
                         'N' nb_var_weight,
                         ps.status,
                         ts.desc_up,
                         ts.system_ind,
                         ts.dept,
                         ts.class,
                         ts.subclass
                    FROM packstore ps,
                         desc_look ts,
                         deps d
                   WHERE ps.store = I_store
                     AND ps.pack_no = ts.sku
                  --   AND (ps.status = I_item_status OR I_item_status IS NULL)
                     AND d.dept = ts.dept
                  )info,
                  deps c,
                  groups b,
                  division div,
                  class a,
                  subclass e
              WHERE c.dept = info.dept
                AND b.group_no = c.group_no
                AND div.division = b.division
                AND a.dept = info.dept
                AND a.class = info.class
                AND e.dept = info.dept
                AND e.class = info.class
                AND e.subclass = info.subclass
   ) tab;
    --
  BEGIN
    --
    -- Instantiate output structure object.
    --
    O_item_data := NB_TAB_ITEM_DETAIL();
    --
    OPEN C_get_info;
    FETCH C_get_info BULK COLLECT INTO O_item_data;
    CLOSE C_get_info;
    --
    RETURN TRUE;
    --
  EXCEPTION
    --
    WHEN OTHERS THEN
      --
      IF C_get_info%ISOPEN THEN
        --
        CLOSE C_get_info;
        --
      END IF;
      --
      O_error_message := SQL_LIB.CREATE_MSG('PACKAGE_ERROR',
                                            SQLERRM,
                                            L_program,
                                            TO_CHAR(SQLCODE));
      RETURN FALSE;
      --
    --
  END GET_STORE_ITEMS;
```

At the worst case, the number of rows returned is ~1.4 million. Is there any way I can boost the performance of the query for such a large number of records? Or should i try a different approach when fetching the data to the output structure? Thanks in advance.

Comment: When you say that the query takes 10 seconds, does that include the time to fetch all the data, or is that just the time to get the initial rows from the database? And how many rows does this cursor return?

Comment: It is only the time to get the initial rows from the database. This cursor is supposed to return at the worst case almost 1 million rows.

Comment: Try adding `NOCOPY` to the `OUT` parameter definitions to reduce memory management overhead. May help.

Comment: OK, so how long does it take to return all the data? Frankly, "minutes" to return a million rows is not unusual in my experience.

Comment: @BobJarvis it took about 3 minutes to return 10k records. And by the way, i checked again the worst case and realized that it will return 1 402 452 rows... The problem here is that there is a time constraint since this function is supposed to support a webservice backend which will be exposed as REST API and has a 55 seconds timeout. In my opinion, "there are no miracles" as such a large amount of data will always take its time. But I want to know if there's any way I can either tune the query or use a different instruction rather than bulk collect to make this process faster.

Comment: @TenG thanks, I will use your advice and check if it helps! :)

Comment: @ruifgmonteiro I doubt the problem is with your PL/SQL code.  The code is already bulk collecting all the records at once, which is usually the fastest way (other than using pure SQL for everything).  This looks like a SQL tuning problem, not a PL/SQL tuning problem.  Run the SQL statement outside of the function and see how it runs.

Comment: I'd echo @JonHeller's comment that it seems like this is likely a SQL optimization problem not a PL/SQL problem.  But more fundamentally, I would seriously question an architecture that potentially returns 1.4 million rows of data from a REST web service and a data model that means that returning a store's inventory requires doing a UNION ALL of three separate queries.  Neither of those make a whole lot of sense.  If you're really stuck with both decisions, can you cache the results rather than materializing them every time?

Comment: What are you going to do once in the cursor? Pretty much you may not need a cursor if you could do it in the select statement or using views on the top of another view. Select is the fastest in sql..

Comment: Using a function with out parameters is bad practice; you should consider converting this to a procedure. Also, why are you pulling the rows into an array, rather than, say, a ref cursor and letting the calling procedure handle the rows? What do you do with the rows once you've retrieved them?

Comment: @Jon Heller, you are right. In order to solve this problem, I introduced pagination in the service. Bulk collect is indeed the fastest way to fetch the results to a table of records. 
Fact, what I did next was opening a sys_refcursor to return the information fetched to the type because that's the expected data structure by the integration. I will post the solution later.
Boneist, why is it a bad practice? In my PL/SQL development experience in my current company this is standard practice. I would like to know more about your position regarding this methodology.
Thanks to everyone!

Comment: @JustinCave you are so right that we ended up changing the approach and we are now using batch to process the records! Thank you for the tips!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I actually solved the problem by adding pagination. As Jon Heller said in the comments, this is not a performance issue related to PL/SQL code. Due to the large number of records returned by the function, there is a need to control how much data it is supposed to return when called. Based on that, I improved the cursor to limit the returned subset of data and optimized the query in an attempt to reduce its cost. I also introduced pagination and defined a limit of records of 1000.

```
FUNCTION GET_STORE_ITEMS(I_store           IN   STORE.STORE%TYPE,
                         I_item_status     IN   WIN_STORE.STATUS%TYPE,
                         --------- pagination ----------
                         I_offset          IN   PLS_INTEGER  DEFAULT NULL,
                         I_limit           IN   PLS_INTEGER  DEFAULT NULL,
                         O_total_reg       OUT  PLS_INTEGER,
                         ----------- output ------------
                         O_item_data       OUT  SYS_REFCURSOR,
                         ----------- error -------------
                         O_error_message   OUT  VARCHAR2)
  RETURN BOOLEAN IS
    --
    L_error_message    VARCHAR2(500)     := '';
    L_skip             PLS_INTEGER       := I_offset;
    L_take             PLS_INTEGER       := I_limit;
    L_limit_take       PLS_INTEGER       := 1000;
    L_tab_item_detail  NB_TAB_ITEM_DETAIL := NB_TAB_ITEM_DETAIL();
    --
    CURSOR C_get_total_rec IS
      --
      SELECT COUNT(1)
        FROM (
              -- based on the main query --
              -- ...
              );
    -- Get store items information.
    CURSOR C_get_info IS
      --
      SELECT NB_REC_ITEM_DETAIL(sku            => sku,
                                item_desc      => desc_up,
                                system_ind     => system_ind,
                                status         => status,
                                div_no         => division,
                                div_desc       => div_name,
                                group_no       => group_no,
                                group_desc     => group_name,
                                dept_no        => dept,
                                dept_desc      => dept_name,
                                class_no       => class,
                                class_desc     => class_name,
                                subclass_no    => subclass,
                                subclass_desc  => sub_name,
                                var_weight_ind => nb_var_weight,
                                primary_ean    => (SELECT upc as primary_ean
                                                     FROM upc_ean u
                                                    WHERE u.sku = tab.sku
                                                      AND u.primary_upc_ind = 'Y'
                                                      AND rownum = 1)
                               )
        FROM ( -- main query --
              -- ...
              ) tab
          WHERE ROWNUM <= L_skip + L_take;
    --
  BEGIN
    -- get the total number of records.
    OPEN C_get_total_rec;
    FETCH C_get_total_rec INTO O_total_reg;
    CLOSE C_get_total_rec;

    -- Set the pagination parameters to get all records by default.
    IF L_skip IS NULL OR L_skip < 0 THEN
      --
      L_skip := 0; -- setting offset to 0
      --
    END IF;
    --
     IF L_take > L_max_take OR L_take < 0 OR L_take IS NULL THEN
        --
        L_take := L_max_take;
        --
      END IF;
    --
    OPEN C_get_info;
    FETCH C_get_info BULK COLLECT INTO L_tab_item_detail LIMIT 1000;
    CLOSE C_get_info;
    --
    -- Open item data sys_refcursor.
    --
    OPEN O_item_data for
      --
      SELECT *
        FROM TABLE(L_tab_item_detail);
    --
    RETURN TRUE;
    --
  EXCEPTION
    --
    WHEN OTHERS THEN
      --
      -- ...
      --
      RETURN FALSE;
      --
    --
  END GET_STORE_ITEMS;
```

Thank you all!